# Where to store authentication data for browser user

Tags: security, http, session

I have few ideas where im not sure if Im correct and if my approach is correct.
The situation is that I got some backend server(s) which exposes REST (of course stateless) interface and expects usage of HTTP authentication via its headers. Then I have some its clients and one of them is web server which has loaded web application that is accessed by typical web browser (using SSL). User via web browser enters his credentials (username and password), which are sent to web server and here comes the thing I want to ask. Web server will delegate all the requests to backend server (REST) putting those credentials to HTTP headers. Is it safe to store those credentials within HTTP session between web server and browser? And if not, where to store them otherwise?

Thanks:-)

Comment: Are backend and web server in the same domain, or is that network shared with others?

Comment: well they are. Actually whole system should be deployable into the some cloud enviroment (lets say for example Amazon) and I guess that nodes in such enviroment are in same domain (or is it unsure?).

Comment: Can the webserver communicate with the REST interface over SSL? If that could be done then I guess the credentials would be safe.

Comment: i will be now commenting to the post under this one

Answer (score 0):

for as long as you using session.abandon at the end of the session(application exit or close) all your data should be in theory safe. 
Make sure that you close session when application shuts down or user idle for too long.
I usually give no more then 20 minutes. Over HTTPS even less.